# Inverse function without the original function

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, inverse

I am going through this paper, '[Certifiable Quantum Dice Or, True Random Number Generation Secure Against Quantum Adversaries](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/pubs/dice0.pdf)' by Vazirani and Vidick. In 'Our results' section on the page 2, it says:

> Let $n$ be an integer, and $ε > 0$ a parameter such that $ε$ is at
>   least an inverse polynomial in $n$.

My question is how can I know the inverse polynomial if I don't know the original polynomial? Wouldn't it be simpler if they had just said $ε$ is a function of $n$?

Update: There is a relation between $ε$ and $n$ on page 3. It is $ε = n^{-\alpha}$ where $n$ is an integer and $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: URL of the paper fixed.

Answer (score 1):

By $\varepsilon$ is at least an inverse polinomial in $n$ they mean that $1/\varepsilon$ is at most a polinomial function of $n$ i.e. for some $\alpha>0$
$$
\varepsilon(n) > \frac{1}{n^\alpha}
$$